VBA code to extract value from one cell and add to a predetermined cell on another worksheet in the same workbook
i have 2 tables on worksheet "Register", (1st table data on G27:K33; second data table on R43:AZ45) the tables aggregate data (integers) entered from another worksheet. I need a code to help in extracting each integer to a corresponding cell on another worksheet "Report" after a click of a button (1st table on E11:I17; and second table on E49:AM51). Such that when i click multiple times, data imported from "Register" worksheet should not override previous data on tables in "Report" worksheet, but should add up (if cell value was 2, an incoming 4 should make cell value = 6), and all values in tables in "Register" worksheet should be erased (just the value to be erased, each cell should maintain formatting and formulas). Both the Register" and "Report" worksheets should also have a "clear all entries" button to clear any values existing in the tables without clearing the formatting and formulas.
I came up with the following code:
Sub CopyAndAggregate()
'Setting variables
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
'Setting variables for source and destination worksheets
Set wsSource = Worksheets("Register")
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Report")
'Copy data from tables in Register and Paste in the Report tab
Call wsSource.Range("G27:K33").Copy(wsTarget.Range("E11:I17"))
Call wsSource.Range("R43:AZ45").Copy(wsTarget.Range("E49:AM51"))
'Clear table entries without clearing formatting and formulas
wsSource.Range("G27:K33").ClearContents
wsSource.Range("R43:AZ45").ClearContents
End Sub

This code returns the following issues:

it does not display any of the data copied from tables G27:K33 and R43:AZ45 in "Register" worksheet to the specified tables E11:I17 and E49:AM51 in the "Report" worksheet. Instead, it copies the formulas which display "#REF" on the tables on "Report".

It deletes all formulas in the tables G27:K33 and R43:AZ45 on the "Register" worksheet.


Am new to VBA and Macros. Please help. Thanks.

IIUC, you want to clear the values from ranges that have formulas, but keep the formulas themselves. That's obviously impossible. The values in those ranges will be the result of the calculation of the formulas they contain. If you want to keep the formulas, the values will be kept as well. The only thing you could do, depending on the formulas, is delete the values used in those formulas as input, which must be in other ranges. Please elaborate on this issue.

E.g. if I have A1 with formula =B1 and B1 contains 1, then of course my A1 also shows 1. To "reset" this, I need to delete the value in B1 (and the new value in A1 will now show as 0 with the formula intact.

wsSource.Range("G27:K33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents for example should only clear cells which have values but not those with a formula.

Copy and Aggregate

There are two different ranges of the same size in each worksheet. The requirement is to identify the cells (hopefully columns) with values (not formulas) and return the sum in the target sheet i.e. Register!G7 = 5, Report!E11 = 1 so the result is Report!E11 = 6. Finally, clear the cells in the source sheet.

Source

Target

Sub CopyAndAggregate()
        
    ' The following two arrays must have the same number of elements.
    Dim SRC_RANGE_ADDRESSES As Variant:
    SRC_RANGE_ADDRESSES = VBA.Array("G27:K33", "R43:S45")
    Dim TGT_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESSES As Variant:
    TGT_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESSES = VBA.Array("E11", "E49")
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Register"
    Const TGT_SHEET_NAME As String = "Report"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(TGT_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim RangesCount As Long: RangesCount = UBound(SRC_RANGE_ADDRESSES) + 1 
    
    Dim srg As Range, svrg As Range, sarg As Range, trg As Range
    Dim aData() As Variant, aValue As Variant
    Dim tData() As Variant, tValue As Variant
    Dim rOffset As Long, cOffset As Long
    Dim n As Long, fRow As Long, fCol As Long
    Dim ar As Long, ac As Long, arCount As Long, acCount As Long
    
    For n = 1 To RangesCount
        Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE_ADDRESSES(n - 1))
        fRow = srg.Row
        fCol = srg.Column
        Set trg = tws.Range(TGT_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESSES(n - 1)) _
            .Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set svrg = srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not svrg Is Nothing Then ' cells containing constants found
            tData = trg.Value
            For Each sarg In svrg.Areas
                arCount = sarg.Rows.Count
                acCount = sarg.Columns.Count
                If arCount + acCount = 2 Then
                    ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): aData(1, 1) = sarg.Value
                Else
                    aData = sarg.Value
                End If
                rOffset = sarg.Row - fRow
                cOffset = sarg.Column - fCol
                For ar = 1 To arCount
                    For ac = 1 To acCount
                        aValue = aData(ar, ac)
                        tValue = tData(ar + rOffset, ac + cOffset)
                        If VarType(aValue) = vbDouble Then ' aValue is a number
                            If VarType(aValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                                aData(ar, ac) = aValue + tValue
                            'Else ' not a number
                            End If
                        Else ' aValue is not a number
                            If VarType(tValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                                aData(ar, ac) = tValue
                            'Else ' not a number
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next ac
                Next ar
                trg.Resize(arCount, acCount).Offset(rOffset, cOffset) _
                   .Value = aData
            Next sarg
            svrg.ClearContents
            Set svrg = Nothing
        'Else ' cells containing constants not found
        End If
    Next n
    
    MsgBox "Copied and aggregated.", vbInformation
            
End Sub


Set svrg = Nothing should follow svrg.ClearContents, no? In its current position, it will cause an error. I don't see where the OP explicitly states the requirement as you have (cogently) defined it here. If that is indeed the requirement, this looks nice :)

You are right on all accounts, but it looks like this is the requirement to me. I fixed the mistake in the code. Thanks.

WOW! Thank you so much. I am still going through the code. Is it possible to leave 'directional' comments for each block of code? like to help me understand what the next set of lines are meant to achieve (am new and still finding my footing in coding & VBA)! Am sorry, but am trying to learn as much as possible from this, and at the moment, am getting lost in this maze of code! Otherwise this is amazing
